# Matplotlib Plot inline and in separate window in a single run

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

I am using Spyder 5 ide, I want to make plots of function b() inline (displayed inside spyder under plots), while plots of function a() should open in a separate window. but it plots both inline in the first run and separate windows in subsequent runs.

```
def a():
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.ion()
    mpl.use('Qt5Agg')
    plt.plot([1,1,1],[1,2,3])
    print(mpl.is_interactive())
    plt.show()

def b():
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.ioff()
    plt.plot([1,1,1],[4,5,6])
    print(mpl.is_interactive())
    plt.show()

b()
a()
```